# Cross platform mobile app development

Tags: iphone, windows-phone-7, mobile

I am looking into the possibility of doing some mobile app development, firstly for Iphone and then later possibly for Windows phone and Android.  I am familiar with .NET development and am wondering about what options to consider.  I have read a little about Mono Touch and Phone Gap, what are the advantages and disadvantages of these and are there any other better options anyone could recommend? Or is it really necessary to learn Objective C for Iphone, and Silverlight for Windows phone etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/). Its a pretty decent cross platform app creator for iPhone and Android.

However, the problem is that Android and iPhone (and Windows Phone) are **different** platforms. For instance, iPhone has navigation controllers with title bars and Android doesn't. Thus you can put buttons in the title bar on iPhone, but not on Android. Eventually you get to the point where you're writing specific code for each platform, even though you're supposed to be writing once and deploying to many places.

Personally the overlap isn't worth the time saved. It makes the code base much more complicated and less maintainable. Plus you can't do as much with those cross platform tools as you can if you do everything natively.

Lastly, who doesn't want to learn a new skill? Why do something the easy/quick way when you could learn how to make iphone, android and windows phone apps natively, which may help you in the future with freelance work or indeed your career.

Comment: Genuine, non-sarcastic +1 for "why do something the easy way" - the easy way is too often the path to mediocrity.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tutorial on setting up a cross-platform solution in C# and [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) tools. It doesn't cover ios, but it's extendable in that direction.

[How to Create a Cross-Platform Solution for Android, WP8 and WinRT](http://code-advisor.com/mono/how-to-create-a-cross-platform-solution-for-android-wp8-and-winrt/)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap or Titanium is good platform for fast development very simple applications. But when you need to go deeper, you will find a lot of pitfalls. And the most important that all this cross-platformed frameworks, based on JavaScript, that they are VERY SLOW!

So for my opinion, the best solution for development cross-platform application is Mono (MonoTouch and MonoDroid). With Mono, you can develop for iOS, Android and WP7. And you business and data-logic remains unchanged. UI-layer you have to write different for each platform. But I think it's even better, because each platform has its own approach. In addition, you get really fast speed with Mono, as it is translated into native code.

But it is not free.

Answer (score 0):

Using a cross platform framework will make your app look non-native on every device, this can be ok if you want to brand your whole app.

This will mean you can only make a standard app and won't be able to take advantage of the nice stuff each os has to provide.

I would go for iPhone -> Android -> Web Mobile -> Windows Phone. In that order.

Porting from iphone to Android has it's caveats but is pretty straight forward as similar design patterns were used. Windows Phone is a bit more industrial in it's design and you might not be able to get your head round the differences.